# What is the exact use case of Minimum face size in ML KIT?

Tags: firebase, face-detection, firebase-mlkit, vision-api, google-mlkit

As per the official documentation,

Minimum Face Size:  float (default: 0.1f) - The minimum size, relative to the image, of faces to detect.

So, is it like it will detect the faces only if it's matches this size ?

I've tested and couldn't get any reasonable results.

I don't want the face to be detected if it's too small.

Comment: Hi Rajesh, can you please elaborate on what you've tried? What was your expectation and what was the outcome?

Comment: Hi Rajesh, have you found any solution for this? I got stucked with same problem.

Answer (score 2):

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/mlkit/vision/face/FaceDetectorOptions.Builder#setMinFaceSize(float)

Based on the documentation, the Face size is the minimum size to be detected. If you do not want to detect too small faces, please increase the number, i.e, setting it as 0.5 or 0.8 to only detect large faces.

Comment: This doesn't work as written in docs. Even if you set minFaceSize to 1, it detects small faces

Comment: Having the same issue. The parameter doesn't seem to have an effect on the min size of the face detected.